# Can I use a slug address to respond for a WordPress domain?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns, slug

I would like to resolve the following situation:

I have a **WordPress website** with address **[www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)** with two slugs **[www.mywebsite.com/subsite1](http://www.mywebsite.com/subsite1)** and **[www.mywebsite.com/subsite2](http://www.mywebsite.com/subsite2)**. I would like to know if I can have two different domains pointing one to each slug, like this:

- **[www.subsite1.com](http://www.subsite1.com)** using slug **[www.mywebsite.com/subsite1](http://www.mywebsite.com/subsite1)** and
- **[www.subsite2.com](http://www.subsite2.com)** using slug **[www.mywebsite.com/subsite2](http://www.mywebsite.com/subsite2)**

It's possible? All domains will be on the same hosting server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like Apache or Nginx as a forward proxy server to display the content of those subdomains onto a top-level domain, but you're going to have a lot of challenges with paths.

Fully-qualified paths (starting with http(s)://) will still contain the old domain name.

Relative paths (starting with /) will be broken since there is a directory level difference.

If you want to make it work, you will likely need to do some url rewriting, which both webservers support.

You won't be able to do this on standard cheap webhosting companies. Best bet is to buy a basic Linode or Digital Ocean server to allow you to host your own Apache/Nginx.

Comment: Hi Dean! Thank you for your help. Today I use a VPS server on Dreamhost, and the pages run on Apache. I don't know if I'll make it with this structure.

Comment: Dreamhost is notoriously slow. I recommend Linode or Digital Ocean instead. Even their $5/mo plan is likely WAY faster than Dreamhost. Good luck to you!

Comment: Also, if you like my answer, can you upvote it and accept it?